# Enum Class Operator Overload no match found for operator

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading, enum-class

I'm attempting to overload some operators for an Enum class.
I get a compiler error saying it's unable to find the operator

**In Enum.h**

```cpp
enum class SomeEnum : unsigned
{
    Test0 = 0,
    Test1  = (1 << 0),
    Test2  = (1 << 1),
};
```

**In Enum.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Enum.h"
#include <type_traits>
SomeEnum operator|(SomeEnum lhs, SomeEnum rhs)
{
    return static_cast<SomeEnum > (
        static_cast<std::underlying_type<SomeEnum >::type>(lhs) |
        static_cast<std::underlying_type<SomeEnum >::type>(rhs)
    );
}
```

**in main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Enum.h"
int main()
{
  SomeEnum blah = SomeEnum::Test1 | SomeEnum::Test2; 
}
```

The compiler spits out an error saying:
no match for 'operator|' (operand types are 'SomeEnum ' and 'SomeEnum ')

Answer (score 0):

You need to add declaration of `operator|` to `Enum.h` file:

```
enum class SomeEnum : unsigned
{
    Test0 = 0,
    Test1  = (1 << 0),
    Test2  = (1 << 1),
};

SomeEnum operator|(SomeEnum lhs, SomeEnum rhs); // added
```

Without this declaration in `main.cpp` after including `Enum.h` compiler can see only definition of `SomeEnum`, but it is not aware of presence `operator|` defined in `Enum.cpp`